# Kitchen Aid KSMC50S stand mixer attachments and dough hook

Tags: equipment, dough, stand-mixer

I inherited a Kitchen Aid KSMC50S stand mixer from my mother. It was purchased new around 1998 or so.

My model has a sticker right above the accessory port that says "No attachments available for this model."

- Why not?
- What makes this model different than the others that accept accessories?
- Is it even true?

The dough hook I have is a replacement. The bowl-lift is calibrated to match the beater attachment depth (it is very tight but doesn't hit the bowl and picks up everything). However, the dough hook sits about 3/4 inch off the bottom of the bowl.

While mixing 4-5 cups of flour (two loaf recipe) dough, much of the dough stayed at the bottom of the bowl and never climbed the hook like the recipe says, even after 10 minutes (much longer than the recipe said it would take).

- What is the correct/expected clearance below the dough hook?

The replacement hook is a spiral type.

- Is this type compatible with this mixer?
- If not can you please direct me to the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because it is a commercial mixer, the normal KitchenAid accessories are not NSF rated. Regular KitchenAid accessories should work just fine, but there are stainless steel NSF rated accessories from other manufacturers available if you cross reference the part numbers.